# BusinessHours.isWithin() Not Working As Expecting

Tags: apex, businesshours

I am using the BusinessHours class and am just running some basic tests:

```
BusinessHours bh = [SELECT Id, ThursdayStartTime FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault = true];
if (BusinessHours.isWithin(bh.Id, scheduledDateTime)){ //this will come up as FALSE if the time isn't between 06:00:00.000Z and 17:00:00.000Z
    system.debug('BusinessHours.isWithin is true:: '  + scheduledDateTime + ', biz hours: ' + bh.ThursdayStartTime);
}
else {
    schedDateTime = BusinessHours.nextStartDate(bh.Id, scheduledDateTime);
    system.debug('BusinessHours.isWithin() is false:: ' + scheduledDateTime + ', biz hours: ' + bh.ThursdayStartTime);
}
```

This prints out: `BusinessHours.isWithin is false:: 2018-08-29 07:00:00, biz hours: 06:00:00.000Z`

Why would it be false if 7:00am is within the registered business hours?

Comment: this will come up as FALSE if the time isn't between 7am - 6pm M-F <--- This time that you specified what is the time zone? Is it possible that you are looking at the database time which is GMT?

Comment: **1.** What is the TimeZone set in your Business Hours? **2.** Can you also provide how are you constructing the `scheduledDateTime`? **3.** Do you have holidays defined?

Comment: I am running the tests in PST and the `Z` is UTC which means that the UTC time is 2:00pm.  Am I incorrect with the UTC information? Could the BusinessHours class be running in a different timezone?

Comment: @JayantDas - 1. I believe the timezone is UTC 2. scheduledDateTime is being passed from a user input from a flow (this COULD be the issue, as the user input is actually inputting a DATE only. But after some discovery the flow forces a DateTime to be passed which is why I am collecting the scheduledDateTime as a DateTime). `Datetime scheduledDateTime = (Datetime)request.inputParameters.get('varStartDate');`

Comment: @Olivia do you mean the TimeZone is in GMT as : `(GMT+00:00) Greenwich Mean Time (GMT)`

Comment: @JayantDas I thought the timezone came in as UTC for BusinessHours but either way, it should still pass as `true`.

Comment: Not really. TimeZone is set in the Business Hours (in setup), so may like to verify that. The scheduledDate returned will be in GMT. So if the TimeZone is set in PT then 7a in GMT is not within the working hours in PT.

Comment: @JayantDas I just double checked and you are right, the BusinessHours are set to GMT.

Comment: Then it must be your `scheduledDate` which is causing issue here. You may like to verify which time zone that date reflects. Because if the `scheduledDate` too is in GMT, then it should have returned `true`